# Ways to reach "Todra Gorge" from "Fez" by public transport? (Morocco Travel)

Tags: tips-and-tricks, morocco

I am going to travel to Morocco in November. We want to travel to "Todra Gorge" from "Fez".

Can anybody suggest me how to reach "Todra Gorge" from "Fez" by public transport?

Is it safe to travel to "Todra Gorge" by a rental car (considering am not so experienced driver)?

Comment: Why the scare quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Not really on topic but I don't mind taking a downvote for sharing my experience. I was staying in nearby Tinerhir. The choice was to spend £70 on a 4x4 or about 50 pence on a shared taxi. Guess which? I would worry about getting back to Tinerhir later.

This is how the shared taxi works in Morocco. The drivers call out their destination and leave when full. They take up to 6 passengers: 2 in the front and 4 in the back. My first trip was in the back on a long town-to-town journey. It was so cramped that we had to lay one shoulder on the neighbour, kipper fashion. Every so often, by mutual consent, all 4 would twist the other way so the opposite shoulders overlapped. There was a French woman in the front who had bought both places in the (single) front seat, and thereafter that is what I did.

To get back from Todra Gorge to Tinerhir, I winged it and started walking and tried to hitch a ride, looking out for a taxi or bus. After a while, a car with four off-duty soldiers picked me up. No problem.

BTW a **fez** is a hat, the Moroccan town is **Fes**.

Comment: As to driving in a foreign country, my rule is never to drive after dark, even though I am an experienced driver.

Comment: It is what it is, but "Fez" is the (or at least an) English spelling of the city's name; you can argue how reasonable this is, but it's what you see if you look on Wikipedia, for instance. Fes is certainly a more truthful transliteration from the Arabic, but that has relatively little bearing on the spelling of the placename as rendered in the English language.

Comment: @davidvc whatever, I just googled *fez wikipedia* which it says it's a hat. So the sensible thing is to spell them to differentiate. And Google Earth has that city as **Fes**.